# How do I run a method inside of a class with thread from ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, rubygems

**I have a class and attributes there**

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name
  def say_hello
   puts "person name #{self.name} "
  end
end
```

**Now I want execute the method say_hello but with this thread**

```
queue_thread= []
1..100.times do |number|
  person= Person.new
  person.name= number.to_s
   thread_to_run=Thread.new {person.say_hello}
   queue_thread << thread_to_run
end
queue_thread.map {|thread_current| thread_current.join}
```

***do you have some idea how do it ? I looked and the proplem is than thread is not recognition the vars by instance of object.***

**the answers correct should be this in console**

```
"person name 1"
"person name 2"
"person name ..."
"person name etc"
```

Comment: What do you get? As a note having multiple threads writing to the console at the same time is a good way to get things mixed up. One thread should handle output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edited again and I need to get the person name 1, person name 2, person name 3 by console. could you please help me ?

Comment: If you need this in order, threads are going to mess things up. Why are you threading things? You'll need to collect that output somehow and sort before displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with this code is that it fires off multiple threads before calling `join` - in this time, some of the threads could be called in incorrect order, owing to the asynchronous nature of threads.

One option would be to simply `join` as soon as the thread is invoked. This will in effect pause the iteration until the thread completes, so you know they'll stay in order:

```
100.times do |number|
  person= Person.new
  person.name= number.to_s
  Thread.new {person.say_hello}.join
end
```

Note there is really no point in using a thread here, but it will at least show you can `join` works.

Another option (which also unnecessarily uses threads) is so delay the thread invocation by storing it as a lambda. This is basically the same thing but allows you to split it up into two iterations:

```
queue_threads= []
1..100.times do |number|
  person= Person.new
  person.name= number.to_s
  thread_lambda = -> { Thread.new {person.say_hello} }
  queue_threads.push(thread_lambda)
end
queue_threads.map {|thread_lambda| thread_lambda.call.join}
```

Also note that `1..100.times` isn't doing what you think it is. It is the same thing as saying `100.times`, so, for example, if you said `99..100.times`, the 99 is ignored and it would be 100 iterations and not only 1. If you want to iterate over a range, you could use something like `99..100.each do |i|`.